# How to create a demo app on iOs (in AppStore)

Tags: ios, app-store

I need to demonstrate to the client that app I'm creating for them is working, and they want to see it real iPhone device. Its working in xCode simulator. But is it possible to publish some how just a demo app  (that is not finished) in AppStore? I just think that it wont pass the apple's review process. What may be the solution?

Comment: You can do 1 thing :[Create a distribution certificate](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/ad-hoc-distribution-build-for-iphone/) with the client's device id and append the same with your app. Archieve your app and create ipa file. Then you can deploy the ipa file to the client which they can test on their own real devices.Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a registered developer with Apple's Developer Program (http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) then you can upload your demo application to I believe 5 devices for testing. If you're not a registered developer now, however, you will need to be when publish your app anyways, so you may want to register now -- just remember it's $99/year.

If you'd rather wait and register later, but upload it now, it looks like there are a number of solutions if you're willing to jailbreak your iDevice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way. Instead of Appstore submission. You can use TestflightApp. Here You can send build to your client or team mail.
See belowlink
https://testflightapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to push it to AppStore, just set your device as the build target to use the app. However, you need to do some settings. You can refer it [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action).

Comment: Tried the link it says: You do not have access to the page you requested. I'm new to iOs app devopment, do I need to enroll payed the developer program to do this?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR you need to buy one. Mum, there's a free choice: `The iOS Developer University Program` either.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ADHOC Distribution Certificate at the Developer Portal, build your app in XCode with that and deliver the buildt app together with the certificate to your client (as a download, or via email). Your client then can install the app via iTunes.

You need the UDID of his iPad, there are several free apps in store to read and send the uDID directly from device.